# How do I "override" the by-extension type of a file in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, file-extension, file-type

CMake seems to make assumptions about files - specifically, what to compile source files with - based on their extension. While this can sometimes be manually overwritten using compiler flags (e.g. `-x C++` for `.c` file), that's dependent on specific compilers and seems like circumventing the problem.

Is there a way to tell CMake "treat a file with extension `.ext1` as though it had extension `.ext2`"? I can't seem to find something like that in the CMake documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the [`LANGUAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) of a file by using 
[`set_source_files_properties'](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html)

> LANGUAGE
>
> What programming language is the file.
>
> A property that can be set to indicate what programming language the
>   source file is. If it is not set the language is determined based on
>   the file extension. Typical values are CXX (i.e. C++), C, CSharp,
>   CUDA, Fortran, and ASM. Setting this property for a file means this
>   file will be compiled. Do not set this for headers or files that
>   should not be compiled.

Comment: Yes, this answer my question, so +1 and will soon accept; but if I wanted to treat the file once as a certain type then again in another place as another type, this probably won't help me.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Could you like use `configure_file` with `COPYONLY` to create a copy of that source file, and add it separately?

Comment: @Nazar554: Yes, I could do that I suppose.